# angular bootstrap drop down items to opens on left

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `ngbDropdown`. By default drop down items shows on the right side. The item gets invisible if the drop down alignment is right most of the page.

Here is HTML

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block float_right">
   <span id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle class="cursor-pointer">Sort by</span>
   <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
      <button class="dropdown-item">Name</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Date of creation</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried class `dropdown-menu-left` but it did not work. How can I align drop down item to show on left side so that text don't break?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have solved it by putting `placement="bottom-right"` in main div.
Updated html is

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block float_right" placement="bottom-right">
   <span id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle class="cursor-pointer">Sort by</span>
   <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
      <button class="dropdown-item">Name</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Date of creation</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have this problem using "SB Admin Angular5 BS4" (actually updated to Angular6) in Dropdown User Info in upper right of the page... your solution solves the issue perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

**Adding to the officially accepted answer, using Angular 8:**

When adding `placement="bottom-right"` property to a tag that is a descendant of a tag with the `navbar` class, you'll also have to add `display="dynamic"` to it.

The default for children of `navbar` classed tags is `display="static"`, and Sony-Khan's solution did not work for me until I added the override. [Ng-bootstrap docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/positioning#dropdown) state:

> When dropdown is used inside the Bootstrap's navbar, it will not be positioned (to match Bootstrap behaviour and work fine on mobile). You can override it by using the display input.

So, modify the opening tag in the example code above to:

```html
<div
  ngbDropdown
  class="d-inline-block float_right"
  placement="bottom-right"
  display="dynamic"
  >
  ...
</div>
```

I am concerned about the part in the docs that says that `static` is the default so it *"matches Bootstrap behaviour and works fine on mobile"*. I won't be able to test my solution on mobile for now, and in the meanwhile will be grateful for a more detailed description on what exact side-effects can be expected from applying the override.

Comment: THIS is what fixed it for me! Thank you!